# matplotlib uppercase tick labels

Tags: python, matplotlib, strftime

I'm trying to set the x-axis tick label in matplotlib (2.1.0) (Python 3.6.3  | Windows 10) to uppercase by adding the pattern with the flag `%^b` like this ([plot code](https://gist.github.com/cccruzr/3c3f8fbf832a617c4347424c7c5350b2)):

```
ax.xaxis.set_minor_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%^b'))
```

However I'm getting the error

```
ValueError: Invalid format string
```

With `%b` I get the plot without any error:

[image]

Additionally, I'd like to remove the first and last tick labels to avoid the repetition.

I wonder if you know any workaround for my problem.

Comment: Please come up with a minimal working example, with some code. I.e. some idealized plot which contains only those features that you are really interested in. See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 2):

In python a string is converted to upper case via `str.upper()`. You may apply this via a `matplotlib.ticker.FuncFormatter` to the labels produced via the `DateFormatter`

```
fmt= lambda x,pos: mdates.DateFormatter('%b')(x,pos).upper()
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.FuncFormatter(fmt))
```

[image]

Complete example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker

x = pd.date_range("2001-01-01", "2001-12-31", freq="5D")
y = np.random.rand(len(x))

fig, ax=plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x,y)

ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.MonthLocator())
fmt= lambda x,pos: mdates.DateFormatter('%b')(x,pos).upper()
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.FuncFormatter(fmt))

plt.show()
```