# Format time axis year as number and month as uppercase abbr

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to find a way to format the datetime axis to display years as numbers and months as uppercase letters. Unfortunately, Python's `strptime` function doesn't provide uppercase month names (e.g. APR). I need to format it myself, but I haven't been able to figure out how. Since I only want to show Apr, Jul, Oct. I used a `MonthLocator` in a `ConciseDateFormatter`. I have tried the following:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.dates import MonthLocator
from matplotlib.dates import ConciseDateFormatter
from matplotlib.ticker import FuncFormatter

x = pd.date_range('2016-01-01', '2021-12-31', freq='M')
y = np.random.rand(len(x))

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 8))
locator = MonthLocator((1, 4, 7, 10))
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(locator)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(
    ConciseDateFormatter(
        locator, formats=['%Y', '%b', '%d', '%H:%M', '%H:%M', '%S.%f']
    )
)
ax.tick_params(axis='x', labelsize=8)
ax.plot(x, y)
```

[image]

But I want the axis to be

```
2016 - APR - JUL - OCT - 2017 - APR - JUL -OCT - 2018 -
```

I've tried [a few ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49397437/matplotlib-uppercase-tick-labels), but none of them works. Once I use a user-defined `FuncFormatter`, it will no longer respect my `ConciseDateFormatter`. I'm wondering what the easiest way is for me to achieve my desired outcome. Should I simply write a formatter function that includes an if statement? If the year and month are both equal to 1, it should display the year number; otherwise, it should show the month name. If this is the case, how can I accomplish it?

Comment: The date formatters use `strfmtime` from the `datetime` module (https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.strftime).  If you want something else, indeed suggest using `FuncFormatter`.

Comment: I've tried "%^B" in `formats` param of ConciseDateFormatter. It didn't really work. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.dates import MonthLocator, num2date
from matplotlib.ticker import FuncFormatter

x = pd.date_range('2016-01-01', '2021-12-31', freq='M')
y = np.random.rand(len(x))

# Custom formatting function
def custom_date_formatter(x, pos):
    dt = num2date(x)
    if dt.month == 1:
        return dt.strftime('%Y')
    return dt.strftime('%b').upper()

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 8))
locator = MonthLocator((1, 4, 7, 10))
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(locator)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(FuncFormatter(custom_date_formatter))
ax.tick_params(axis='x', labelsize=8)
ax.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

Expected result:
[image]

Comment: Could u take a look at this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77115609/format-time-axis-to-only-display-tick-labels-after-a-certain-date) I wonder if it is a bug or i missed something.