# Format time axis to only display tick labels after a certain date

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am attempting to format the time axis in subplots so that the xtick label appears only after the start of the data.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import date

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.dates import MonthLocator, num2date
from matplotlib.ticker import FuncFormatter

xs = [pd.date_range(f'{y}-07-01', '2021-12-31', freq='M')
      for y in range(2016, 2019)]
ys = [np.random.rand(len(x)) for x in xs]

fig, axs = plt.subplots(3, 1, figsize=(10, 8))
for ax, x, y in zip(axs, xs, ys):
    ax.plot(x, y)

    # Custom formatting function
    date_min = x[0].date()
    def custom_date_formatter(x, pos):
        dt = num2date(x)
        if dt.date() < date_min:
            return ''
        elif dt.month == 1:
            return dt.strftime('%Y')
        else:
            return dt.strftime('%b').upper()

    ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(MonthLocator((1, 4, 7, 10)))
    ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(FuncFormatter(custom_date_formatter))
    ax.tick_params(axis='x', labelsize=8)

    ax.set_xlim(date(2016, 7, 1))
```

But I got a plot where all axis display identical xtick labels:

[image]

But I want them to be:

```
JUL - OCT - 2017 - APR - JUL - OCT - 2018 .....

..... JUL - OCT - 2018 - APR - JUL - OCT - 2019 .....

............ JUL - OCT - 2019 - APR - JUL - OCT - 2020 .....
```

[image]

How should I fix the `custom_date_formatter` function to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### The issue you are encountering is due to having defined the function within the loop and relates to what is called [closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming))

For example, consider the following simplified but essentially identical algorithmic situation:

```py
functions = []
for i in range(3):
    def print_i():
        print(i)
    functions.append(print_i)

for f in functions:
    f()
```

which gives the following perhaps unexpected output (just as in your question):

```
2
2
2
```

Due to the function having been redefined with each iteration of the loop, when all three from the appended list are called, it is only the last definition of the function that remains defined - hence the output is identical rather than `0, 1, 2`.

---

### Changing your code to move the `custom_date_formatter` function out of the subplots axes loop

```py
from datetime import date
from functools import partial

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

from matplotlib.dates import MonthLocator
from matplotlib.dates import num2date
from matplotlib.ticker import FuncFormatter


def generate_data(start_year, end_year):
    """Generate random data between given years.
    
    Args:
        start_year (int): The starting year for the date range.
        end_year (int): The ending year for the date range.
    
    Returns:
        tuple: A tuple containing two lists:
               - A list of pandas date_range objects from June of the 
                start_year to December 2021.
               - A list of numpy arrays containing random float values for 
                each date in the respective date_range.
    """
    date_ranges = [
        pd.date_range(f"{y}-06-01", "2021-12-31", freq="M")
        for y in range(start_year, end_year)
    ]
    data_values = [np.random.rand(len(dr)) for dr in date_ranges]

    return date_ranges, data_values


def custom_date_formatter(x, date_min):
    """Custom date formatter for the x-axis.
    
    Args:
        x (float): The raw x-coordinate value from the plot. Represents a date 
                   in the matplotlib's float format.
        date_min (datetime.date): The minimum date to be displayed on the 
                   x-axis.
    
    Returns:
        str: Formatted date string. If the date is less than date_min, an 
             empty string is returned. If the date corresponds to January, the 
             year is returned. Otherwise, the month's abbreviation is 
             returned.
    """
    dt = num2date(x)
    if dt.date() < date_min:
        return ""
    elif dt.month == 1:
        return dt.strftime("%Y")
    else:
        return dt.strftime("%b").upper()


def plot_data(date_ranges, data_values):
    """Plot data with custom x-axis formatting.
    
    Args:
        date_ranges (list): A list of pandas date_range objects to be plotted 
                            on the x-axis.
        data_values (list): A list of numpy arrays containing the y-values for 
                            each date_range.
    """
    fig, axs = plt.subplots(len(date_ranges), 1, figsize=(10, 8))

    for ax, dates, values in zip(axs, date_ranges, data_values):
        ax.plot(dates, values)

        bound_formatter = partial(
            lambda x, pos: custom_date_formatter(x, dates[0].date())
        )
        ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(MonthLocator((1, 4, 7, 10)))
        ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(FuncFormatter(bound_formatter))

        # Code to remove x ticks with blank labels:
        ticks = ax.get_xticks()
        labels = [bound_formatter(tick, None) for tick in ticks]
        update_ticks = [
            tick for tick, label in zip(ticks, labels) if label != ""
        ]
        ax.set_xticks(update_ticks)

        ax.tick_params(axis="x", labelsize=8)
        ax.set_xlim(date(2016, 7, 1))

    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()


# Generate data and plot
date_ranges, data_values = generate_data(2016, 2019)
plot_data(date_ranges, data_values)
```

[image: Plot with ticks removed where label blank]

Comment: Thanks a lot. Do you know how to hide unlabeled ticks? I attempted to use `ax.xaxis.get_ticklabels()` to retrieve the ticks with no labels, but it appears that I cannot individually control a tick.

Comment: Thx. Your code definitely works, but everything is coverted to a function and they are nested. I'm trying to implement your example but I couldn't figure out how. I defined custom_date_formatter(x, pos, date_min=None) and add pos as a arg given matplotlib's convention, and then use  FuncFormatter(partial(custom_date_formatter, date_min=dates[0].date())). It works, but what should I pass to hide the ticks? I'm having trouble understanding when there are three nested functions in your code. (it's me)

Comment: Well in the example code I provide you actually don't pass `pos` to the `custom_data_formatter` function. That will throw an error likely. I used `pos` in the `partial`/`lambda` function - which is a little complex yes. Is that what you're confused about? I've updated the answer condensing it into just one example and one code block. The code produces the plot shown when run exactly as is.

Comment: And to further clarify/explain (and I added a comment in the code to highlight this), the code added which removes x ticks with blank labels works by re-using the `bound_formatter` "_closure_" function (meaning, a function definition with a specific set of enclosed arguments bound to it - see https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial on partials; this is the crucial part of the algorithm design in this approach which ensures that each subplot is properly _distinctly_, i.e. independently, customized/altered - in this case specifically the x axis via `x`)

Comment: Indeed, it was unclear to me why we needed to use the formatter again and what was being passed to it and returned. Thank you for the update. Since it seems like we need to reset the entire xticks anyway, I simply used zip(aaxs[i].get_xticks(), axs[i].xaxis.get_ticklabels()) to retrieve xticks with a non-empty labels. It also seems to work. Thank you very much!

Comment: Interesting I'm not 100% sure what you implemented with your use of `zip` but please feel free to propose an edit to my answer if there's a better way of accomplishing this. It is not that I am resetting the labels when calling `bound_formatter` again - we call it again because the formatting of the particular subplot was _bound_ to the function itself - it is actually only used to check which ticks to remove, and it is the call to `ax.get_xticks()` and then subsequently `ax.set_xticks()` which uses the already formatted ticks and labels except having dropped all the blank ones. AFAIU